# Два обработчика событий сразу в jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте, друзья! 
В jQuery есть два обработчика событий для окна: изменение размера экрана (resize) и скролл (scroll). Как сделать, чтобы событие (в частном случае - присвоение переменной высоты блока с id) обрабатывалось при любом из действий? Понимаю, что можно просто записать код два раза, но, думаю ,есть какое-то решение красивее?

```
$(window).resize(function() {
        nav_height = $('#stick_menu').height();
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
            nav_height = $('#stick_menu').height();
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[метод `on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) позволяет в первом параметре указывать несколько событий разделенных пробелами.

Например так:

```
$(window).on('scroll resize', function() {
    nav_height = $('#stick_menu').height();
});
```

Comment: Нужно разбираться с азами))) спасибо большое!

Comment: @ИгорьВойнов На этом сайте вместо спасибо есть галочка под рейтингом ответа для принятия ответа как полезного (или правильного)